# Recursive search in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm incredibly new to Perl, and never have been a phenomenal programmer. I have some successful BVA routines for controlling microprocessor functions, but never anything embedded, or multi-facted. Anyway, my question today is about a boggle I cannot get over when trying to figure out how to remove duplicate lines of text from a text file I created.

The file could have several of the same lines of txt in it, not sequentially placed, which is problematic as I'm practically comparing the file to itself, line by line. So, if the first and third lines are the same, I'll write the first line to a new file, not the third. But when I compare the third line, I'll write it again since the first line is "forgotten" by my current code. I'm sure there's a simple way to do this, but I have issue making things simple in code. Here's the code:

```
my $searchString = pseudo variable "ideally an iterative search through the source file";
my $file2 = "/tmp/cutdown.txt";
my $file3 = "/tmp/output.txt";
my $count = "0";

open (FILE, $file2) || die "Can't open cutdown.txt \n";
open (FILE2, ">$file3") || die "Can't open output.txt \n";
    while (<FILE>) {
        print "$_";
        print "$searchString\n";
        if (($_ =~ /$searchString/) and ($count == "0")) {
            ++ $count;
            print FILE2 $_;
            } else {
            print "This isn't working\n";
        }
    }
close (FILE);

close (FILE2);
```

Excuse the way filehandles and scalars do not match. It is a work in progress... :)

Comment: Have you checked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30173/how-to-remove-duplicate-lines-inside-a-text-file)?

Comment: How do I implement this line into my code?

$ perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;' input_file > output_file

Comment: Why do you need the code then?

Comment: as a side note, there are no file _handlers_  only file _handles_

Comment: The one-liner already does everything you need. It's the same as what you want to do, just in a lot less words. If you want to fully write it out, you need to read your file, use a hash to count which lines you have seen (and I mean literally full lines) and simply write only the ones that have not been seen.

Comment: or handles... yes, excuse the typo. @raina77ow, the code is part of a larger program to search test programs for components used in smaller programs, then pare down the ouput file of it's duplicates. So, the code needs to be implemented inside an executable. Does that answer? Again, I'm a noob. Potato even... Thanks.

Comment: >> `perl -MO=Deparse -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;'`

Answer (score 4):

The secret of checking for uniqueness, is to store the lines you have seen in a hash and only print lines that don't exist in the hash.

Updating your code slightly to use more modern practices (three-arg `open()`, lexical filehandles) we get this:

```
my $file2 = "/tmp/cutdown.txt";
my $file3 = "/tmp/output.txt";

open my $in_fh,  '<', $file2 or die "Can't open cutdown.txt: $!\n";
open my $out_fh, '>', $file3 or die "Can't open output.txt: $!\n";

my %seen;

while (<$in_fh>) {
  print $out_fh unless $seen{$_}++;
}
```

But I would write this as a Unix filter. Read from `STDIN` and write to `STDOUT`. That way, your program is more flexible. The whole code becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;

while (<>) {
  print unless $seen{$_}++;
}
```

Assuming this is in a file called `my_filter`, you would call it as:

```
$ ./my_filter < /tmp/cutdown.txt > /tmp/output.txt
```

**Update:** But this doesn't use your `$searchString` variable. It's not clear to me what that's for.

Comment: This is a subroutine in a program designed to remove the duplicate lines from a txt file I created earlier by grepping filenames, including paths, from another file. The intent of this subroutine is to cut down the duplicates from the txt file and produce an output file without duplications. I should of been more clear in my post, thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @WetCheerios that doesn't change anything about this answer. It's still perfectly valid. You should be able to transfer Dave's code into a subroutine just fine.

Comment: @simbabque: Except the Unix filter bit, I guess.

Comment: Perhaps it is just too elegant for me to grasp. I'll try to implement the key part of the code using what I have already in place, and remove the parts that are redundant, or worthless, till I get ti to work. Thanks!

Comment: Redundant! Worthless!! There's nothing in my code that is redundant or worthless :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your file is not very large, you can store each line readed from the input file as a key in a hash variable. And then, print the hash keys (ordered). Something like that:

```
my %lines = ();
my $order = 1;

open my $fhi, "<", $file2 or die "Cannot open file: $!";
while( my $line = <$fhi> ) {
   $lines {$line} = $order++;
}
close $fhi;

open my $fho, ">", $file3 or die "Cannot open file: $!";

#Sort the keys, only if needed
my @ordered_lines = sort { $lines{$a} <=> $lines{$b} } keys(%lines);
for my $key( @ordered_lines ) {
   print $fho $key;
}

close $fho;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two things to do that:

- a hash to keep track of all the lines you have seen
- a loop reading the input file

This is a simple implementation, called with an input filename and an output filename.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh_in, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "Could not open file '$ARGV[0]': $!";
open my $fh_out, '<', $ARGV[1] or die "Could not open file '$ARGV[1]': $!";

my %seen;

while (my $line = <$fh_in>) {

    # check if we have already seen this line
    if (not $seen{$line}) {
        print $fh_out $line;
    }

    # remember this line
    $seen{$line}++;
}
```

To test it, I've included it with the DATA handle as well.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {

    # check if we have already seen this line
    if (not $seen{$line}) {
        print $line;
    }

    # remember this line
    $seen{$line}++;
}

__DATA__
foo
bar
asdf
foo
foo
asdfg
hello world
```

This will print

```
foo
bar
asdf
asdfg
hello world
```

Keep in mind that the memory consumption will grow with the file size. It should be fine as long as the text file is smaller than your RAM. Perl's hash memory consumption grows a faster than linear, but your data structure is very flat.

Comment: Also note that nothing about your question is _recursive_.

Comment: I'm supremely confident this is an absurdly ignorant question to ask, but how are the filenames being assigned to $fh_in and $fh_out? Again, I am very new to perl, and appreciate the assistance.

Comment: @WetCheerios through the argument list. I meant to include an example call but it seems I forgot. Sorry.